# htaccess RewriteRule with variables, anyone?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is wrong with this code! arghhh!!

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+) tags.php?tag=$1 [NC]
```

I'm trying to clean my URL up to http://mydomain.com/tags/tag names here

from http://mydomain.com/tags.php?tag=tag names here

Comment: what happens whenyou go to ^^http://mydomain.com/tags/tag^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the extract from your local (`.htaccess`) or global (`httpd.conf`) config?

- If global, the rule should start with `/` (`RewriteRule ^/tags/([^/]+) tags.php?tag=$1 ...`).
- If local it should be in the document root (e.g. `/var/www`). Check the permissions (`www.www 640`).

If does not help, enable logging:

```
RewriteLog       /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel  2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a $ sign in there

```
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)$ tags.php?tag=$1 [NC]
```